# Comparing The Correct Responses of Different Sections of a Test

Tags: chi-squared-test

I have the results of an exam for 21 students. The exam has 144 correct/incorrect questions with three equal Sections (48). I want to confirm if the difference in the correct/incorrect answers for each Section is different than the overall correct/incorrect.

For example, Student A had an overall mark of 70% (101/144): Section A 98% (47/48), Section B 73% (35/48), and Section C 40% (19/48).

I was thinking that I could do a Chi-Square test comparing the observed results against the expected, based upon the overall score. Using the example of Student A, based upon the overall mark (70%) I would expect the distribution to be 31 Correct and 17 Incorrect in all three Sections.

Assuming the same percentages applied to all answers to the tests, that would give me:

| Observed | Section A | Section B | Section C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Correct | 987 | 735 | 399 |
| Incorrect | 21 | 273 | 609 |
| TOTAL | 1008 | 1008 | 1008 |

| Expected | Section A | Section B | Section C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Correct | 706 | 706 | 706 |
| Incorrect | 302 | 302 | 302 |
| TOTAL | 1008 | 1008 | 1008 |

However, I feel like I'm doing this wrong.

It's been awhile since I did something like this, and this analysis is only a side part of a larger project, so I'm worried I've pulled the wrong concept from memory.

Can anyone tell me if I've simply overthought this and there is a simpler test, and/or if this is the wrong way to be doing this type of Chi-Square?

In particular, something in the back of my mind makes me think that I'm doing it wrong by including each student's total numbers rather than comparing the percentages somehow, but at this point I have read so much in a short time that I've ended up less confident that I even understand basic addition.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks fine to me. You would now compute `(observed - expected)^2 / expected` for each of the 6 cells in your table (e.g., `(987-706)^2/706=111.84` for the top-left cell), take the sum, and compare it to the critical values of the Chi-square distribution.